# the frontend don't receive any data from the backend (the server send an object the frontend don't receive anything)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, knex.js

the server send an object to the frontend but the frontend don't receive anything so the function onOrderSubmitCOD stops at sending the form , so there is no result of conditions (navigate() , loadUser()), any solution for that

order.js (backend) expressjs knex js:

```
const handleOrderCOD = (req,res, db) => {
const {firstname, lastname, email, mobilenumber, adress, city, size, quantity} = req.body;
if(!firstname || !lastname || !email || !mobilenumber || !adress || !city || !size || !quantity)
    {return  res.status(400).json('no data to load')};
db.insert({
        
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname:lastname,
        email:email,
        mobilenumber:mobilenumber,
        adress:adress,
        city:city,
        size:size,
        quantity:quantity,
        joined: new Date()

       
    
    })

.into('orders')
.returning('*')

    .then(user =>{
        if(user){
              res.json(user[0]) 
        } else{
            res.status(400).json('unable to order1')
        }

    })
    .catch(err=>res.status(400).json('unable to order2'))
}
```

order.js(front end) react.js

```
function Order(props) {
   const navigate = useNavigate();


  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [mobileNumber, setMobileNumber] = useState('');
  const [adress, setAddress] = useState('');
  const [city, setCity] = useState('');
  const [size, setSize] = useState('');
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState('1');






 function onOrderSubmitCOD  ()  {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/orderCOD', {
      method: 'post',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        firstname: firstName,
        lastname:lastName,
        email: email,
        mobilenumber: mobileNumber,
        adress: adress,
        city: city,
        size:size,
        quantity: quantity

      })
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(user => {
        console.log(user)
        if (user.id) {
         
          props.loadUser(user);
          
          navigate('/orderCompleted'); 
        }
      })
  }
```

app.js (frontend) react.js

```
const initialState= {
   
    user: {
      id: '',
      firstname: '',
      lastname: '',
      email:'',
      mobilenumber:'',
      adress:'',
      city: '',
      size:'',
      quantity: '',
      joined:''
    }


  }






class App extends Component {
 constructor(){
  super();
  this.state= initialState;
}
   

    loadUser = (data) => {
  this.setState( {user:
      {       id: data.id,
      firstname: data.firstname,
      lastname:data.lastname ,
      email:data.email,
      mobilenumber:data.mobilenumber,
      adress:data.adress,
      city: data.city,
      size:data.size,
      quantity: data.quantity,
      joined:data.joined
        }})
}


render() {
    return (
     <>
  <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Navbar /> }>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="order"> 
          <Route index element={<Order  loadUser={this.loadUser}/>} />
          <Route path="orderCompleted" element={<OrderCompleted />} />
        </Route>
      
          <Route path="collab" element={<Collab />} />
          <Route path="art" element={<Art />} />
         
          <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
         </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
<Footer/>
</>
    );
  }
 

} 

export default App;
```

Comment: Add catch too might be your backend triggered some error.

Comment: @AsadHaroon i have one catch in the server , where I add the second

Comment: Please clarify "the frontend don't receive anything"... Are you getting a response from the backend? If so, what's the status code? If not, do you get any error on the client? If you inspect the call on browser's devtools what do you see? What is `console.log(user)` actually logging? `undefined`? Nothing at all?

Comment: @lbsn the problem that i get nothing on the devtools but when I console log user on the backend a get the object I want

Comment: Add .catch() in frontend too like fetch('http://localhost:3000/orderCOD', {
      method: 'post',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        firstname: firstName,lastname:lastName,email: email,mobilenumber: mobileNumber,adress: adress,
        city: city,size:size,quantity: quantity }) })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(user => {
        console.log(user)
        if (user.id) {
          props.loadUser(user);
          navigate('/orderCompleted');  }
      }).catch((e)=>console.error(e));

Comment: @MAMOCHACH Provided the API call is fired you should at least be able to inspect it in the Network tab on Chrome devtools. And that call should result in something, might be a server response or a connection error or just a failed status. If, on the contrary, the call is not fired at all then something is wrong in a part of your code you're not showing us.

Comment: @lbsn the data goes to the database but when I want to return a response to the frontend from the server I get nothing , what I can show u from the code , I will add it

Comment: It's hard to tell what's happening there without a reproducible example. Maybe you could post the whole React component and the route definition from your backend. But the main point is that neither we nor you can extract any helpful information from a description like "I get nothing" . In order to effectively debug the issue you should try and answer some specific questions: Is the client getting any response (even with empty body) from the backend? If so, what's the status code? 200 or 400? Is your `console.log(user)` on the frontend getting fired at all?